# Excel sheet does not display exported chart image - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, export-to-excel, bar-chart

I have a web page in my website that allows me to download the chart from that page and add it to an excel sheet. However, a  red x button with the words: "this image cannot currently be displayed" is shown in place of the chart. I have tried many solutions online but all of them show the same outcome.

Here are my codes:

```
    protected void ExcelDl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string tmpChartName = "test2.jpg";
        string imgPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + tmpChartName;
        Chart1.SaveImage(imgPath);
        string imgPath2 = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/" + tmpChartName);

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.xls;");
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        string headerTable = @"<Table><tr><td><img src='" + imgPath2 + @"' \></td></tr></Table>";
        Response.Write(headerTable);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

Any form of help will be greatly appreciated. Also, do note that I have added the required codes in my Web.config.

Answer (score 0):

We have tried your program and here it’s working fine. Excel downloaded along with image. I have installed in iis and tried with many client machine and it was working fine.

Not sure what’s going on your end. The problem might be wrong image path reference will cause this problem. Print image URL and make sure whether it is correct or not.

Alternate method: instead of using html tags inside the excel cell use XML closing method to render the image inside the excel cell.

Here I have added sample code for the Closed XML methods to render the image in excel. to use this code need to refer the following DLLs 
1. ClosedXML.dll
2. WindowsCore.dll
3. DocumentFormat.OpenXML.dll
4. PresentationCore.dll

Reference Link for Closed XML methods: https://closedxml.codeplex.com/

```
      using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
    IXLWorksheet WorkSheet = new IXLWorksheet();
      string LogoPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Themes/Images/logonew.png");
      System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(LogoPath);
      if (bitmap != null)
         {
            var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
            if (stream != null)
            {
                stream.Position = 0;

                XLPicture pic = new XLPicture
                {
                     NoChangeAspect = true,
                     NoMove = true,
                     NoResize = true,
                     ImageStream = stream,
                     Name = "Logo",
                     EMUOffsetX = 4,
                     EMUOffsetY = 6
                };

                XLMarker fMark = new XLMarker
                {
                    ColumnId = 1,
                    RowId = 1
                 };

                 pic.AddMarker(fMark);

                WorkSheet.AddPicture(pic);
             }
          }

           Response.Clear();
           Response.Buffer = true;
           Response.Charset = "";
           Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
           Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.xls");

           using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
           {
            wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
            MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
           }

}
```

Please check and let me know your comments.

Comment: hi @Mayil, sorry for the late reply. The image URL was able to open just fine but when its opened in Excel, the problem shows up. I'll try this and let you know of the result.

Comment: Thanks for the update. try and let me know your comments.